# Best approach for database design

Tags: database-design, index

I have 4 tables `users`, `posts`, `categories`, `categories_map`

`posts` has `id`, `text`, `category_id`
`categories_map` contains `user_id` and `category_id`

My goal is to make an queue that user can preview. Also, user will be able to skip some posts or edit text in them. If user skipped post it will never appear in queue. However, user is not able to change sequence because cron will be executing script.

First approach I think is to create a table that will contain
`user_id`, `post_id`, `text_modified`, `is_skipped`, `last_posted`. So when cron job will be executed it will leave a timestamp and next time this post won't be grabbed and user easily can change text for this post.

Second appoach to create separate table where queue will be generated for user `user_id`, `post_id`, `category_id`, `text_modified`. And cron job can easily job follow this table and remove row after it was done. But with this approach if I will have 30 users with average 3 categories that contains 5000 posts each my table will have 450000 rows already. Yes if it will be indexed properly it should be all good. But will it be scalable after I will have 100-200 users?

Which approach should I go or is there any other solution?

Comment: You state solution proposals, but not what problem you're trying to solve. Please state, what you want to achieve and why.

Comment: @Grimaldi What I want to achieve is showing preview of queue to user with ability to skip post and modify text of this post. I need this because I have cron job that executed every 15 min and will be posting 1 post for each user from this queue.